# How can I write a makefile to auto-detect and parallelize the build with GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

Not sure if this is possible in one Makefile alone, but I was hoping to write a Makefile in a way such that trying to build any target in the file auto-magically detects the number of processors on the current system and builds the target in parallel for the number of processors.

Something like the below "pseudo-code" examples, but much cleaner?

```
all:
    @make -j$(NUM_PROCESSORS) all
```

Or:

```
all: .inparallel
    ... build all here ...

.inparallel:
    @make -j$(NUM_PROCESSORS) $(ORIGINAL_TARGET)
```

In both cases, all you would have to type is:

```
% make all
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

UPDATE: Still hoping for an example Makefile for the above.  Not really interested in finding the number of processes, but interested in how to write a makefile to build in parallel without the -j command line option.

Comment: Don't try to do it within one Makefile.  The standard technique, as far as I can tell, is to have a trivial top-level Makefile that calls another, in this case using something like $(MAKE) -j $(NUM_PROCESSORS) -f $(THE_REAL_MAKEFILE).

Comment: The real solution would be to use an alternative for make that is based on a more powerful process modelling technique, but I don't know any good candidate (I do for the technique, but not for the tool).

Comment: As [this unix.stackexchange.com reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208569) shows, just use make -j$(nproc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After poking around the LDD3 chapter 2 a bit and reading dmckee's answer, I came up with this not so great answer of using two makefiles (I would prefer just one).

```
$ cat Makefile
MAKEFLAGS += -rR --no-print-directory

NPROCS := 1
OS := $(shell uname)
export NPROCS

ifeq ($J,)

ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
  NPROCS := $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
else ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
  NPROCS := $(shell system_profiler | awk '/Number of CPUs/ {print $$4}{next;}')
endif # $(OS)

else
  NPROCS := $J
endif # $J

all:
    @echo "running $(NPROCS) jobs..."
    @$(MAKE) -j$(NPROCS) -f Makefile.goals $@

%:
    @echo "building in $(NPROCS) jobs..."
    @$(MAKE) -j$(NPROCS) -f Makefile.goals $@
$ cat Makefile.goals
MAKEFLAGS += -rR --no-print-directory
NPROCS ?= 1

all: subgoal
    @echo "$(MAKELEVEL) nprocs = $(NPROCS)"

subgoal:
    @echo "$(MAKELEVEL) subgoal"
```

What do you think about this solution?

Benefits I see is that people still type `make` to build.  So there isn't some "driver" script that does the `NPROCS` and `make -j$(NPROCS)` work which people will have to know instead of typing make.

Downside is that you'll have to explicitly use `make -f Makefile.goals` in order to do a serial build.  And I'm not sure how to solve this problem...

UPDATED: added $J to above code segment.  Seems work work quite well.  Even though its two makefiles instead of one, its still quite seamless and useful.

Comment: I like this a lot... I wouldn't worry about the serial build too much, though you might try some more environment variable tweaks. Something like "J=1 make" is shorter.

Comment: Ah yeah, I suppose I could do `make J=1` and that'd be simple enough.

Comment: If you change `all` in your `Makefile.goals` to say `goal` and merge the two files together, then call `@$(MAKE) -j$(NPROCS) $@`, doesn't it work?

Comment: NPROCS:=$(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS) on windows, inherited from the automatic environment variable of the same name.  You'd have to detect the OS differently.  %OS% / $(OS) exists though.

Answer (score 25):

The detection part is going to be OS dependent. Here's a fragment that will work on Linux and Mac OS X:

```
NPROCS:=1
OS:=$(shell uname -s)

ifeq($(OS),Linux)
  NPROCS:=$(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
endif
ifeq($(OS),Darwin) # Assume Mac OS X
  NPROCS:=$(shell system_profiler | awk '/Number Of CPUs/{print $4}{next;}')
endif
```

To get it working you are probably going to have to re-invoke make. Then your problem is preventing infinite recursion. You could manage that by having two makefiles (the first only resetting the `-j` value), but it is probably possible to finesse it.

Comment: You can work around the recursion using environment variable... the Linux kernel build system is a great example of this

Comment: I'm more curious in how to implement the recursion than detecting the number of cpus which is quite simple in comparison IMO.

Comment: @Sam I'm somewhat familiar with the kernel build system.  Can you give me a hint as to where in the build system I could find this specific usage?

Comment: NPROCS:=$(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS) on windows, inherited from the automatic environment variable of the same name.

Comment: "Number Of CPUs" isn't found in the huge/slow return from OSX 10.10.

Comment: For Mac OS X, you can improve the system_profiler usage by limiting the information to only the hardware data - e.g. `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType`. Then you could use a similar command as above: `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Total Number of Cores/{print $5}{next;}'`. Instead of using system_profiler though you could use `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`, just realize it could report some different since it also includes HyperThreading cores. For my 13" Intel Core i5 (early 2015) the system_profiler reports 2 cores whereas sysctl reports 4. You could use `sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu`.

Answer (score 8):

I just added this to the top of my Makefile. It lets make create any number of jobs, but tries to keep the load average below the number of cpu cores.

```
MAKEFLAGS+="-j -l $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) "
```

Note this is Linux specific.

Comment: Unfortunately, this sort of thing doesn't work well for all situations so experiment with this carefully before using.  I've experimented with it and had it wildly fluctuate between way too many parallel jobs and building in serial until the load average drops below the threshold.

Comment: Even shorter: `MAKEFLAGS+="-j $(shell nproc)"` - note that you may easily shoot yourself in a foot with this

Comment: Note that this does not work in GNU Make version 4.2. Any older version or version 4.3 should be fine. For details, see http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?48274

Comment: I prefer `JOBS ?= $(shell nproc)` followed by `MAKEFLAGS += -j $(JOBS) -l $(JOBS)`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I went with:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
        NUMPROC := $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
else ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
        NUMPROC := $(shell sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $$2}')
endif

# Only take half as many processors as available
NUMPROC := $(shell echo "$(NUMPROC)/2"|bc)

ifeq ($(NUMPROC),0)
        NUMPROC = 1
endif
```

Comment: Instead of passing `sysctl` output through `awk`, simply ask for the value only: `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`

Comment: A simplest way to determine the OS (works on old Linux and Mac) is
`NUMPROC=\`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN\``

Answer (score 5):

I'll skip over the `$(NPROCS)` detection stuff, but here's how you could do this in a single `Makefile` (this is probably GNU Make specific, but that looks like the variant you're running):

```
ifeq ($(NPROCS),)
# Code to set NPROCS...
%:
    $(MAKE) -j$(NPROCS) NPROCS=$(NPROCS)
else
# All of your targets...
endif
```

See [Defining Last-Resort Default Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Last-Resort) and [Overriding Part of Another Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles) in the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc_Top).

Answer (score 2):

If I read the question correctly, the goal is to parallelize the build process as much as possible. The `make` man page states the following

> If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.

Isn't this basically the solution that you want? If your Makefile has enough parallel targets you will use all your CPUs and if the targets are not parallel, that `-j` option won't help anywas.

Comment: This is an equivalent of fork bomb if you have hundreds of source files.

Comment: It appears that is what Eclipse does when using the parallel build option "Use optimal jobs number"

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be automatic, then you can override your typical make command to be an alias to itself in your `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Example:

```
alias make="make -j"
```

Or you could do something like:

```
alias jmake="make -j"
```

in the case that you don't want to override it, but want a quick and easy (and memorable) way to run make in parallel.

Comment: The idea is to make it work for anyone that uses the source, not require changes to each developers environment.