# Is there a way to get the -j parameter from a make invocation?

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, scons

Lets say I call:

```
make -j 5
```

Is there a way, within my `Makefile` to get the `-j` parameter ?

My goal is to call `scons` from a `Makefile` a to keep the ability to use several jobs to fasten compilation.

Something like:

```
# The Makefile
all:
    scons -j ${GET_J_PARAMETER}
```

Thank you.

Foot note: I know I should better call `scons` directly but some of the developers where I work have been typing `make` for almost ten years and it seems impossible for them to type anything else to build their libraries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `MAKEFLAGS` contains that information.

Read more about it here [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Section 7.3 explains how to test for a specific parameter.

Comment: This doesn't actually work - the j flag is special and doesn't appear completely in MAKEFLAGS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778389 has more workarounds that may help.