# how to: make -j x // where x is automatically determined

Tags: bash, makefile, alias

After reading answer to this question:
[Make "make" default to "make -j 8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151605/make-make-default-to-make-j-8)

I am wondering if there is way to make the -j option automatically use the correct number of compile threads?

So I say `make`. And the `make` command itself uses 6 or 4 or 8 threads depending on the hardware?

Comment: What do you mean with _correct number of compile threads_?

Comment: @maba usually the recommendation is to use the number of cpu cores x 2. So for a a dual core cpu, it should be -j 4.

But some recommend as many compile threads as cores. So -j 2 for a dual core cpu.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4778389/946850

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`make` does not look up the number of cores by itself if you just use `make -j` -- instead, it parallelizes to the max. However, you should be able to determine the number of cores by

```
grep -c "^processor" /proc/cpuinfo
```

or (as per Azor-Ahai's comment, if available on your system)

```
nproc
```

Hence:

```
make -j $(nproc)
```

See "How [How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6481005/946850)" for more details. Also, see [GNU make: should the number of jobs equal the number of CPU cores in a system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499070/946850)

Comment: I think that this isn't the answer that the user want .... But the question isn't very clear...

Comment: @DonCallisto: No, the question is perfectly clear to me: Use `-j 17` if there are 17 cores. I just remembered the semantics of `-j` wrong.

Comment: now your answer have much sense ... remember to add the section where you create the alias ;-)

Comment: @DonCallisto: This has been treated in the referred-to question already.

Comment: Is this any different than using `nproc`?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: I don't think so, thanks for showing me `nproc`!

Comment: One should use `nproc` instead of `cpuinfo` or `lscpu` because `nproc` correctly handles offline cores and CPU affinity. Trying to scale to cores that are not in use is bad.