# Using make with -j4 or -j8

Tags: c, opencv, makefile

I have 4 processors and am compiling a processor-hungry application. I read that using `make` with the `-j4` switch was recommended for OpenCV; should I instead use `-j8`? What is the advantage of making for multiple processors?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4778389/1172302

Comment: Tl;dr: `make -j $(nproc)`

Comment: Also you may add `alias make="make -j $(nproc)"` to your .bashrc

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As you say the `-j` flag tells `make` that it is allowed to spawn the provided amount of 'threads'. Ideally each thread is executed on its own core/CPU, so your multi-core/CPU environment is used to its fullest.

`make` itself does not compile the source files. This is done by a compiler (gcc). The Makefile (input for `make`) contains a set of targets. Each target has a set of dependencies (on other targets) and rules how to build the target. `make` reads the Makefile(s) and manages all targets, dependencies, and build rules. Besides compiling source files you can use `make` to perform any task that can be described by shell commands.

If you set the allowed number of threads too high, it is not possible to schedule each thread on its own core. Additional scheduling (context) switches are required to let all threads execute. This additional resource usage obviously result in lower performance.

There are multiple rules-of-thumb, but I guess that setting to total amount to `<number of cores> + 1` is the most common. The idea behind this is that all cores have their own thread and there is one additional managing thread that handles the targets and which is next to be built.

Comment: Well explained Veger. Thanks much for the answer.

Comment: There is no  additional managing thread, but +1 is good for filling any idleness due to I/O

Answer (score 99):

The answers above are all mostly correct.  However, the details are a bit misleading.  For example, there's no need to add an extra job for a "managing thread" (note: `make` is not actually multithreaded).  `make` never counts itself as a job for the purposes of `-j`, so, as Huygens says above, if you say `-j5` you'll get 5 compile jobs running, not 4 plus make.

The reason most people use [number of cores] + [some padding] has nothing to do with `make` or what it needs, but rather with the nature of the compiler.  A compiler is really just a very complicated text translation tool: it reads in text in one form and converts it to "text" (binary) in another form.  A lot of this (especially as your language gets more complex, like C++), requires a lot of CPU.  But it also requires a lot of disk I/O.  Disk I/O is slow, so while one compiler is waiting for some data from the disk, the kernel schedules other jobs to run.  That is why you can usefully have more than the number of cores compiles running at the same time.

Exactly how large you can get `-j` before you start seeing diminishing returns (your builds actually start going slower, at some point, with more `-j`) depends completely on your hardware, the kinds of builds you're doing, etc.  The only way to know for sure is experimentation.

However, [number of cores]+[a few] is typically a good approximation.

Comment: If the files to be built are very big, [cores]+[something >0] could cause bottleneck, because each thread will be very ocuppied once all the IO operations are done. I use -j cores as max.

Comment: It is useful to run `vmstat` and observe the blocking values.  Also the compiler options may affect this.  Ie, -O0 takes less CPU than -O3, so I/O is more of a factor with un-optimized builds.  I wonder dependency information could be used to optimize disk cache?  [An article](http://www.kaizou.org/2016/09/build-benchmark-large-c-project/) and [code](https://github.com/mnowotnik/build-benchmark); modify `benchmark.sh` and change the `NPROC` variable.  The code structure is synthetic vs real builds, but it is a great starting point for experimenting and evaluation.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that it's not hard to measure a bit on either side. One compiles enough that trying cores + 2 and cores - 2 should be easy to try. Trying is important because the speed of IO subsystems has radically changed in the last 5ish years.

Answer (score 4):

The `-j` option is only use to speed up application build, it determines how many jobs `make` can spawn for the build. You can either set `-j<nb core>` or even higher `-j<nb-core * 1.5>` so that compilation can happen in parallel.

It has no impact on the compiled code.

For a 4 core system, you could try `make -j6`. If make can run parallel builds, it will launch up to 6 simultaneous compilation process (e.g. 6 calls to gcc).

Answer (score 3):

One CPU per thread plus one manager/loader. Since a thread that does disk operations is technically almost idle from CPU point of view, add one to the total number of cores.

If the CPU is using hyperthreading, you can safely count each core as two cores and double the number of threads, so a quad core Intel Core i7 should get -j9 (eight virtual cores plus manager.) On a quad core AMD use -j5

Comment: There is no additional managing thread, but +1 is good for filling any idleness due to I/O