# Is there a point in specifying more than one make job (make -j4) on a single core processor?

Tags: compilation, makefile, jobs

I'm compiling OpenCV on an [AM335x 1GHz ARM® Cortex-A8](http://www.ti.com/product/am3358) (BeagleBone Black's processor). RAM is limited too (512MB DDR3). Is there a point in specifying more than one job, i.e., `make -j4`, like the [installation script](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_9.sh) does?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289250/make-j4-or-j8/15295032#15295032

Comment: Probably `-j4` is too much.  But you might win with `-j2`.  It depends on other factors of your system and also what the recipes in your makefile is actually doing.  Only experimentation will tell.

Answer (score 1):

It can be. Many commands executed by make are I/O bound. If you have only one job, it can often be blocked awaiting I/O. If you have multiple jobs, when one job is blocked awaiting I/O, another might be able to use the CPU, and vice versa. That gives more utilisation of the CPU and I/O system, and thus faster building.