# What's the meaning of dash when use gcc -x c

Tags: gcc, cmake

Run the following command in linux bash:

`# echo 'main() { __asm__("xorb %al, %al"); }' | gcc -x c -`

**Q1**: What's the meaning of the last `-` ?

**Q2**: Whether the `-` is a parameter of `gcc` or `shell` ?

Another `--` when use cmake

`# cmake --build ./build-cmake/Debug/obj --target processor_benchmark -- -j4`

**Q3**: What's the meaning of `--` before `-j4` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Is it possible to get gcc to read from a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe)

The - tells gcc to read from stdin ie. the pipe.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake.1.html

> Pass remaining options to the native tool.

-- will send -j4 to make. [make -j4 or -j8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289250/make-j4-or-j8)